# panda3d bullet rigid body mesh for animated model

Tags: animation, actor, 3d-model, panda3d

I've imported an animated model that's in the gltf format as the Actor class into Panda3d and want to attach a bullet physics rigid body node to it that can update its geometry with the actor's animations. So far, I've only been able to attach an mesh rigid body that doesn't update its geometry with the actors animations. I'm using the Bullet library in Panda3D for this. Is there any way to do this at all?